# draw a box that takes a input as the box size

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python. One of the tasks is to make a box with a dynamic box.

Here's an example of how it's supposed to work:

```
text: ertioe
integer: 40
========================================
=                ertioe                =
========================================
```

Here's my code:

```
print("write in something: ")
string = str(input())

print("write in a integer: ")
integer = float(input())

symbol = '='

print(symbol* (int(integer)+4))
print(symbol, string, symbol)
print(symbol* (int(integer)+4))
```

My box is all wrong:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look so wrong to me. You only need to add some spaces between `symbol` and `string` in the middle line. You should be able to calculate how many by simple arithmetic.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yeah I changed it now, and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to centre align your string to the correct width, replace the middle print statement with:

`print(symbol, string.center(int(integer)), symbol)`

Edit:

Also, in case you aren't aware, you can put the print statements within the `input()`:

```py
string = str(input("write in something: "))

integer = float(input("write in a integer: "))
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the help! I got it almost right, lol. I can accept your answer in 7 min.

Edit: I didn't know that thanks again!